# Match high ASCII characters (but not the letter i)

Tags: regex, powershell, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to match all high ASCII and special utf-8 characters using powershell:

```
gc $file -readcount 0 | select-string -allmatches -pattern "[\x80-\uffff]"
```

which should find all the characters I want.  However, the regular expression seems to be failing as it's matching the character `"i"` and `"I"`.

I ran this to test and I'm baffled:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | select-string -allmatches -pattern "[\x80-\uffff]"
```

Why is it matching `"i"`?  What I also don't get is if you cast the character to an int, the value is 105 which is clearly not within the range specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `i` is matched on `U+0130` (`İ`, "Latin Capital Letter I with dot above"), [a variant of capital `I` found in Turkish](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/):

```
PS C:\> 'i' -match '[\u0130]'
True
```

Try with an inverted pattern:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "[^\x00-\x79]"
```

---

Here is how I found out:

```
0x80..0xffff |ForEach-Object {
    $CharCode = $_.ToString("X4")
    if('i' -match "[\u$CharCode]"){
        "U+$CharCode matches"
    }
}
```

Comment: `[char]0x49 -match '\u0130'` is also True.  Something seems really wrong here.  `i` also matches `\P{IsBasicLatin}`, which is supposed to be "not in 0-127".  A workaround is to use -cmatch.

Comment: @js2010 `[char]0x49 -match '\u0130'` is correct - `[char]::ToLower([char]0x130)` is `i` (`[char]0x49`) :) the match against `\P{IsBasicLatin}` does seem buggy to me too

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity is another workaround for this weird Turkish `İ` bug.  There's a little dot on the top.

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | 
  select-string -allmatches -pattern "[\x80-\uffff]" -casesensitive
```

Or this, but the letter `i` (small or capital) would pass through without -casesensitive:

```
# not 0-127
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | 
  select-string -allmatches -pattern "\P{IsBasicLatin}" -casesensitive
```

The lower case of that foreign character is considered to be the English small letter `i`.  But it doesn't map the other way (in culture en-us).

```
'İ'.tolower()     
i

'i'.toupper()
I
```

The Kelvin `K` also seems problematic.  It's lowercase is a regular small 'k'.  It's taken as ascii when case is ignored.  I'm not sure why it behaves differently than the Turkish `İ`.

```
[char]0x212a | select-string '\P{IsBasicLatin}' # no output
```